# HTML elements and canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to replicate this typing effect and particles from this website: https://caferati.me/. I was able to create the typing effect in the canvas, but he uses html elements.I can't figure out how he was able to add html elements to a canvas, because you need the canvas for the particles. How would you approach this?

Here is what I have right now:

```
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;
let c = canvas.getContext("2d");
console.log(canvas);

//Typing Effect
let i = 0;
let txt = "Lorem ipsum typing effect!";
let speed = 80;
let cursorX = 20;
let cursorY = 80;
let x = 20;
let y = 80;
function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    c.fillText(txt.charAt(i), cursorX, cursorY);
    let letterLength = c.measureText(txt.charAt(i)).width;
    cursorX = cursorX + letterLength;
    i++;
    x += 1;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}

c.fillStyle = "white";
c.font = "15px Arial";
typeWriter();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put `html` elements in canvas currently and in the page you point to the `span` tags are outside of the `canvas`. What you can do is position the `html` elements on top of the canvas (or the canvas below the `html` as it is in the example page) with `position:absolute` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Thank you for your help Velimir.